# How to display a table column using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to show two columns only if $edit = 1 in php/html. So did the following:

```
<?php
   if ($edit == 1)
        {
    <td align="center"><a href="editor/editor.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" onclick="handleLinkClick(event);">Edit</a></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="removedoc.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" onclick="swalremove(event);">Remove</a></td>
         }
?>
```

But I get an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '< on line 177
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: close `php` tag before `td` start and start `php` tag after `td` close

Comment: @Gulshan: Wow. it worked. So I was very close... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

```
<?php
   if ($edit == 1)
      {
     <td align="center"><a href="editor/editor.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onclick="handleLinkClick(event);">Edit</a></td>
     <td align="center"><a href="removedoc.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onclick="swalremove(event);">Remove</a></td>
      }
?>
```

To:

```
<?php
   if ($edit == 1)
   {
    echo '<td align="center"><a href="editor/editor.php?id='.$row['id'].'" onclick="handleLinkClick(event);">Edit</a></td>';
    echo '<td align="center"><a href="removedoc.php?id='.$row["id"].'" onclick="swalremove(event);">Remove</a></td>';
 }
?>
```

OR:

```
<?php if ($edit == 1) { ?>
       <td align="center"><a href="editor/editor.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onclick="handleLinkClick(event);">Edit</a></td>
        <td align="center"><a href="removedoc.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onclick="swalremove(event);">Remove</a></td>
     <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this :

```
<?php
if ($edit == 1) { ?>
    <td align="center"><a href="editor/editor.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" onclick="handleLinkClick(event);">Edit</a></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="removedoc.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" onclick="swalremove(event);">Remove</a></td>
<?php } ?>
```

You need to use proper php tag conventions.
Do not mix HTML with PHP.
Always close the PHP tag before writing raw HTML.
You may also use it with only PHP, like this:

```
<?php
if ($edit == 1) { 
    echo 
    '<td align="center"><a href="editor/editor.php?id='.$row["id"].'" onclick="handleLinkClick(event);">Edit</a></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="removedoc.php?id='.$row["id"].'" onclick="swalremove(event);">Remove</a></td>';
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a HTML string and add to it any element that you might have, then at the end echo it. It is much simpler:

```
$html = '';

if ($edit == 1) {
    $html .= '<td align="center"><a href="editor/editor.php?id=' . $row["id"] . '" onclick="handleLinkClick(event);">Edit</a></td>';
    $html .= '<td align="center"><a href="removedoc.php?id=' . $row["id"] . '" onclick="swalremove(event);">Remove</a></td>';
}

echo $html;
```